# position of spike in the spectrum of a sin wave

Tags: fft

I have a sin wave of 16Hz, sampled at 2048 samples persecond. I performed the FFT of the sequence and did a spectrum plot. My plot gave me two spikes at both ends of the graph. But i was told the spike is meant to be at 16. how exactly am i supposed to do the plotting in order to get this exact spike?

Comment: You are taking 128 samples of each cycle of your sinusoid and so your FFT _will_ have two spikes in it. If you want a spike in the 16th bin, you need to do a FFT of length 2048. If you do a FFT of length 128, you will see a spike at both ends (bins #1 and #127).  This assumes that the bins are numbered from 0 to 127; MATLAB uses a different convention.

Comment: I am having the same challenge, and the FFT i took was that of length 2048, but the spike was still at both ends. So what should be done?

Answer (score 1):

A sinusoid is the sum of two complex exponentials ("negative" and "positive" frequency) so that their imaginary parts cancel out each other:

$$cos(f \cdot t) = \frac{1}{2} \left( exp(f \cdot t \cdot i) + exp(-f \cdot t \cdot i) \right)$$

The Fourier Transform decomposes your input into a weighted sum of complex exponentials. Therefore, you get to see two pulses in the spectrum. One at -f and another at +f, basically. Typically, the "negative half" of the spectrum is located after the positive half because in discrete signals there is no difference between -f Hz and fs-f Hz where fs is the sampling frequency. So, your FFT result's ordering is 0 Hz to almost fs Hz where you can think of the second half as the negative portion of the spectrum.

Since real-valued signals have an imaginary part of zero, you'll notice that the Fourier Transform of real-valued signals always exhibits a symmetry between negative and positive frequencies with a certain kind of phase relationship (same amplitude and negated phase) so that the complex exponentials' imaginary parts cancel between negative and positive frequency.

Complex-valued signals are more general in that their spectra don't have to be symmetric around 0 Hz. The imaginary part helps you distinguish between positive and negative frequencies:

$$exp(f \cdot t \cdot i) = cos(f \cdot t) + i \cdot sin(f \cdot t)$$

As you can see above, the sign of f does not change the real part. But it does affect the sign of the imaginary part.

Answer (score 0):

The second half of your FFT is the conjugate of the first half. Just plot the first half. The frequency resolution is 2048/N where N is the full FFT size.